# Counting L3 cache access event on Amd Zen 2 processors

Tags: linux, x86, cpu-cache, perf, amd-processor

I am trying to figure out the event to use with the perf stat command to count L3 cache accesses on an AMD Zen 2 processor. As per the PPR (http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2017/11/54945_PPR_Family_17h_Models_00h-0Fh.pdf), section 2.1.13.4.1, page 168, the event is x01 and the umask is x80 for "[L3 Cache Accesses] (L3RequestG1)". From what I understand, the event to use in perf stat command would thus be r8001. But the following command always returns the count as zero no matter what load I run:

perf stat -a -e r8001   --  sleep 10

Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

```
             0      r8001
```

10.001105322 seconds time elapsed

Am I misinterpreting the PPR or does [L3 Cache Accesses] (L3RequestG1) mean something else?

Also, is there a way to specify the slice of L3 cache to monitor for events in perf as most of the newer architectures with high core counts have multiple L3 slices.

Comment: Use `/proc/cpuinfo` or `/sys` and read more about [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). You probably want to code your own kernel module.... See https://kernelnewbies.org/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: There are multiple existing kernel modules with light-weight wrappers for PMU hardware, if for some reason you don't want to use `perf` with its `perf list` names for raw events.  libpfc is a simple way to program counters to allow user-space `rdpmc`.  See the author's answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864416/perf-overcounting-mysterious-kernel-work).  IDK if it's Intel-only, but adding AMD support would be easier than starting from scratch. 
And there's likwid which definitely already supports AMD: https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The L3 cache events can only be counted on the L3 PMU as clearly specified in both the physical mnemonic (`L3PMCx01`) and the logical mnemonic (`Core::X86::Pmc::L3::L3RequestG1`) of the event you want to measure. The L3 PMU is formally called L3PMC. This is similar to the cbox PMUs on Intel processors.

The default PMU in perf for raw events is `cpu`, which is the name the perf_events subsystem gives to the core PMU. An event specified using a raw event code without an explicit PMU, such as r8001, is equivalent to cpu/r8001/. The core event 0x001 represents the event `Core::X86::Pmc::Core::FpSchedEmpty` and the umask 0x80 is undefined for this event (see Section 2.1.15.4.1). So you're counting an undefined event. In this case, if the event happened to be implemented but not documented, then the event count may not be zero depending on whether it occurs during the execution of the program being profiled. Otherwise, the event count would be zero. perf_events doesn't stop you from counting undefined events.

Starting with upstream kernel version v5.4-rc1, the L3PMC is supported in perf_events under the name `amd_l3`. To determine whether you're using a kernel that supports this PMU, check whether it's enumerated using the command `ls /sys/devices/*/format`. If not supported, then you can't measure the L3 events on that kernel through perf.

If `amd_l3` is supported, you have to explicitly specify the PMU as in `amd_l3/r8001/` or `amd_l3/event=0x01,umask=0x80/` to have the event counted on the right PMU. Or you can just use the perf event name `l3_request_g1.caching_l3_cache_accesses`.

Do you know what the event `L3RequestG1` represents? The documentation only describes it as "Caching: L3 cache accesses," which isn't very meaningful. It seems to me that the types of transactions it counts are a subset of those covered by the event `L3LookupState`. Table 19 in Section 2.1.15.2 says that L3 accesses and misses should be counted using rFF04 (`L3LookupState`) and r0106 (`L3CombClstrState`), respectively. Don't blindly expect that any of these events actually count whatever you want to measure.

The PPR you linked is not for any Zen2 processors, it's for some Zen and Zen+ processors (specifically models 00h-0Fh). You need to know the processor model and family to locate the right PPR.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I was not aware of the different PMU devices. That document is for 17H family and Zen 2 is part of that family right?

Comment: @user1165136 Family 17h includes Zen, Zen+, and Zen2 processors. Different processors models in this family have different PPR documents. Use `cpuid` to determine the model number of your processor and then find the PPR for that model on AMD's website.