# Measure LLC/L3 Cache Miss Rate on AMD Zen2 CPU

Tags: linux, x86, perf, amd-processor

I have question related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237030/counting-l3-cache-access-event-on-amd-zen-2-processors).

I want to (programatically) measure L3 Hits (Accesses) and Misses on an AMD EPYC 7742 CPU (Zen2). I run Linux Kernel 5.4.0-66-generic on Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS. According to the question linked above, the events rFF04 (L3LookupState) and r0106 (L3CombClstrState) should represent the L3 accesses and misses, respectively. Furthermore, Kernel 5.4 should support these events.

However, when measuring it with perf, I run into issues. Similar to the question linked above, if I run `numactl -C 0 -m 0 perf stat -e instructions,cycles,r0106,rFF04 ./benchmark`, I only measure 0 values. If I try to use `numactl -C 0 -m 0 perf stat -e instructions,cycles,amd_l3/r8001/,amd_l3/r0106/`, perf complains about "unknown terms". If I use the perf event names, i.e. `numactl -C 0 -m 0 perf stat -e instructions,cycles,l3_request_g1.caching_l3_cache_accesses,  l3_comb_clstr_state.request_miss` perf outputs `<not supported>` for these events.

Furthermore, I actually want to measure this using perf's C API. Currently, I dispatch a `perf_event_attr` with type `PERF_TYPE_RAW` and `config` set to, e.g., `0x8001`. How do I get the `amd_l3` PMU stuff into my `perf_event_attr` object? Otherwise, it would be equivalent to `numactl -C 0 -m 0 perf stat -e instructions,cycles,r0106,rFF04 ./benchmark`, which is measuring undefined values.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: Try `-e rFF0F00000040FF04` parameter which is shown in your CPU [PPR doc](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/55803-ppr-family-17h-model-31h-b0-processors.pdf).

**Detailed**:

Maybe I can help you with the first problem which is said in your **3rd paragraph**. The second which is said in 4th paragraph, I can't. Sorry.

Since your cpu is ['Family 23 Model 49'](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/cpuid), then I refered to '17h model 31h' [amd PPR doc](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/55803-ppr-family-17h-model-31h-b0-processors.pdf). It says use `L3Event[0xFF0F00000040FF04]` for 'L3 Accesses ' (`0xFF0F00000040FF04` is 64bits which is same as `L3 Performance Event Select` width as amd doc shows). Also, the `man perf-list` also shows AMD uses this format where it has '32-35' bits. Although in the PPR doc, the `L3PMCx04` doesn't have much information, the doc has some useful infos located in `L3 Performance Event Select`.

I used my cpu ryzen 7 4800h which is [17h_60h](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/cpuid#Family_23_.2817h.29) family [Renoir](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/cores/renoir) processor  (It is also zen2. From these two source code [one](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7796916146b8c34cbbef66470ab8b5b28cf47e83/arch/x86/events/amd/core.c) which lists some encodings for the AMD CPU and [two](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a507db1d8fdc39802415e4d2ef6d1aecd67927fa/tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/amdzen2/recommended.json#L12C41-L12C41), zen2's config should be almost same.) which don't have `amd_l3` support, here I used `ls_dc_accesses` as the representation and `729` is the code of `All DC Accesses` in my cpu family [amd doc](https://www.amd.com/en/support/tech-docs/processor-programming-reference-ppr-for-amd-family-17h-model-60h-revision-a1) where `PMCx029` represents the `EventCode` and 8 corresponding bits represent UMask. It can be also found in the above code [two](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a507db1d8fdc39802415e4d2ef6d1aecd67927fa/tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/amdzen2/recommended.json#L12C41-L12C41) (in your 17h_31h family [PPR doc](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/55803-ppr-family-17h-model-31h-b0-processors.pdf) p182, the number is `0x430729`):

```bash
$ ls /sys/devices/*/format | grep amd_l
$ perf list | grep ls_dc_accesses -A 1
  ls_dc_accesses
       [Number of accesses to the dcache for load/store references]
$ perf stat -e r729 ls          
...
 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

         1,097,092      r729                       
$ perf stat -e ls_dc_accesses ls
...
 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

           974,666      ls_dc_accesses
```

And not everyone has one epyc cpu, so it may be not convenient to see where it goes wrong with your problem. Maybe you can offer more valuable information if possible.

Hope this can help you.