# Why is do...while slower than while when using gcc optimization

Tags: c, performance, optimization, x86-64, do-while

I was playing around with optimization for C programs and used some code for (naively) calculating primes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_prime(int x) {
    int divisor = 2;

    if(x <= 1)
        return(0);
    if(x == 2)
        return(1);
    while(divisor * divisor <= x) {
        if(x % divisor ==  0)
            return(0);
        divisor++;
    }
    return(1);
}

int main(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10000000; i++)
        if(is_prime(i))
            printf("%d is a prime number.\n", i);
}
```

I thought I could boost the performance a little bit by using a `do...while` loop instead of the `while` loop, so that the while condition will never be executed for an even `x`. So I changed the `is_prime()` function to this:

```
int is_prime(int x) {
    int divisor = 2;

    if(x <= 1)
        return(0);
    if(x == 2)
        return(1);
    do {
        if(x % divisor ==  0)
            return(0);
        divisor++;
    } while(divisor * divisor <= x);
    return(1);
}
```

When I compile both version without optimizations (`gcc main.c -o main`) `time ./main > /dev/null` takes about 5.5s for both, where it looks like the `do..while` version performs a tiny bit better (maybe ~40ms).

When I optimize (`gcc main.c -O3 -o main`), I get a strong difference between the two. `time ./main > /dev/null` gives me ~5.4s for the `do...while` version and ~4.9s for the `while` version.

How can this be explained? Is the gcc compiler just not as well optimized for `do..while` loops? Should I thus always use `while` loops instead?

---

My CPU is an Intel i5-4300M.

My gcc version is `gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0`.

I have now tested the clang compiler (`clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)`; `clang main.c -O3 -o main`) as well. Here the results are as expected: `time ./main > /dev/null` takes about 6.5s for the `do...while` version and 6.8s for the `while` version.

Comment: Just checking, are these results repeatable? E.g. if you run each version of the program 10 times, do you find that the time for the `while` version is _consistently_ less than the time for the `do...while` version?

Comment: Yes, they are repeatable. The fluctuation in the results is <50ms.

Comment: OK thanks J. Doe. Incidentally I tried it myself and while I also find consistent results, they're the opposite of yours: for me the `do-while` version is about 7% faster. Of course this could be compiler-dependent (so it would help if you include your compiler version) but is there any chance you might have mixed up two versions of the compiled program? It's not likely, I know, but if you were accidentally running the unoptimized version to get the timing results for the optimized `do-while` version, then everything would make sense. Just trying to rule out the silly stuff.

Comment: I have double checked it again, but I did not switch them up. I'll update the question with my gcc version, thanks for the hint.

Comment: I [compiled both functions on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/a0-ned). Now interpreting the machine language is out of my league :)

Comment: Nice tool, @pmg, but unfortunately I'm not able to interpret the assembler instructions either.

Comment: you can make it faster with `divisor += 2` to skip even divisors, or even [`laststep = 6 - laststep; divisor += laststep;`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode) since a prime divides by 6 results in a remainder of 1 or 5

Comment: Related: [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/204902).  Looking the commented version in my answer might help you understand the compiler output here.  Also, a loop-exit condition based on `n/c > c` is an alternative to actually doing a multiply.  The multiply is basically free in parallel with division on modern out-of-order execution x86 CPUs, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Branch alignment for loops involving micro-coded instructions on Intel SnB-family CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26907523).

Comment: Yup, you have a Haswell CPU, so the differences are probably just due to chance of code alignment creating front-end bottlenecks.  Marking as a duplicate; we can reopen if you find that adding padding to the asm before assembling the compiler-generated asm doesn't change performance in ways that match the results in that question.  (Unfortunately compilers don't optimize for modern CPU architectures in enough detail to avoid minor bottlenecks like this.)

Comment: Did anybody notice that the do ... while one executes 0.5% fewer multiplies and .04% fewer mods than the while() { } one because the divisor is incremented before the loop condition rather than after.   I rewrote it in "bc" and the "do...while" one was quicker there too :)