# Is raising of unexpected exception considered as an implementation defect?

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, language-lawyer, ieee-754

Follow-up question for [Why conversion (unsigned long long)DBL_MAX (or FLT_MAX) causes raising of FE_INEXACT as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66426109/why-conversion-unsigned-long-longdbl-max-or-flt-max-causes-raising-of-fe-ine/66430972#66430972).

Is raising of unexpected exception (`FE_INEXACT`) considered as an implementation defect?

Notes:

1. User @Nate Eldredge confirms that on AArch64 `FE_INEXACT` is not raised.
2. All the hardware powered by Infineon TriCore does not raise `FE_INEXACT`, because the condition to raise `FE_INEXACT` is `inexact && ! invalid`. I.e. it is not possible to have both `FE_INEXACT` and `FE_INVALID` raised.

Reason of the question: need to precisely interpret / classify / categorize this case.

Comment: One of the answers in the other question says this is undefined behavior. That means anything is permitted, so no behavior could be considered a defect.

Comment: Is it considered a defect by whom?

Comment: By the end user. The end user expects only `FE_INVALID`. However, the implementation raises `FE_INEXACT` as well. Does IEEE 754 permit raising of `FE_INEXACT` in addition to required `FE_INVALID`? For example, one my colleague does not see in C / IEEE 754 any direct prohibitions to raise `FE_INEXACT` in this case. What is your view?

Comment: @Barmar _When the C standard does not define a behavior, the behavior may be defined, partially or completely, by other standards_ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65106621/fp-invalid-operation-contradiction-between-c-ub-and-ieee-754-wdb/65107366#65107366). In this case it is IEEE 754. Also (from C standard): _Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment_.

Comment: This sounds more like a quality of implementation issue.